# Как выполнить bash скрипт получаемый по wget с аргументами на локальной машине?

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт расположенный где-то на http сервере, допустим, такого  вида:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

который называется, к примеру, `script.sh`

Есть файл на локальной машине, к примеру, `users_args.txt`, к примеру, такого вида:

```
string one
string thwo
string three
```

Каким образом можно выполнить на локальной машине `script.sh` используя в качестве списка аргументов значения из `users_args.txt` не сохраняя `script.sh` на локальной машине? Так сказать "на лету".

> *Возможно используя конструкцию `wget -q -O- http://server-addres/script.sh | bash` ... НО так будет выполняться только скрипт без аргументов находящихся в файле `users_args.txt`*

Comment: `wget -q -O- http://server-addres/script.sh | bash ` - будет выполняться локально.

Comment: Про аргументы не дочитали. Без аргументов да, будет, а вот  как ему передать аргументы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт на внешем сервере `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1" "ok"
echo "$2" "ok"
echo "$3" "ok"
```

Параметры на локалхосте `params.txt`:

```
f i r s t
second
third
```

Команда:

```
wget -q -O- http://site.ru/script.sh | xargs -d "\n" -a params.txt bash /dev/stdin
```

Comment: Спасибо. Принято.

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил сам ответил.
В скрипте добавляем строку
`[[ -f users_args.txt ]] && readarray -t args <users_args.txt`
и используем значения элементов массива для комманд в скрипте в качестве аргументов.

То есть скрипт данный в вопросе будет выглядеть так:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f users_args.txt ]] && readarray -t args <users_args.txt
echo ${args[@]}
```

И тогда конструкция `wget -q -O- http://server-addres/script.sh | bash` работает

Comment: но интригующая тема «при чём тут вообще wget???» так и осталась, увы, нераскрытой.

Comment: А фразы "Есть скрипт расположенный где-то на http сервере" и "не сохраняя `script.sh` на локальной машине" не навеяли ассоциаций?

Comment: увы, нет: ни из вопроса ни из ответа не очевидно, что бы изменилось, если бы скрипт был сохранён в файле.

Comment: Ничего ровным счетом, даже было-бы гораздо проще организовав `while read arg; do ./script.sh $arg; done<users_args.txt` Но меня интересовало именно такое решение и я об этом спросил.

Comment: в комментарии вы написали совершенно другую логику запуска: три запуска скрипта по разу на каждую строку из файла с аргументами.

Comment: Соглашусь, косяк. Должно быть `echo ${args[@]}`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81827/discussion-between-andrey-karpov-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 0):

вообще вопрос состоит из двух частей.

---

передать параметры скрипту, поступающему интерпретатору *bash* на его *stdin*, можно, например, так:

```
$ echo 'echo x$1' | bash /dev/stdin yz
xyz
```

---

ну а передать какой-либо программе содержимое файла в виде «одна строка файла — один параметр» несколько сложнее. пока придумалось только в два шага:

```
$ readarray -t a < файл
$ программа "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: задал [вопрос на англо-сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51903026/4827341). (пришлось добавлять в вопрос прописные буквы. чёртовы граммар-наци!)

Comment: ))) Собственно мой вопрос был следствием вопроса [Там же](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889123/how-can-i-feed-input-within-bash-executed-through-the-network/51890683?noredirect=1#comment90733153_51890683) ))))) . Вот такая рекурсия ))))

Comment: `echo -e "-l\n-a\n-H" > params.txt` `cat params.txt | xargs ls`

Comment: Круто, а теперь попробуй все тоже самое но создав ситуацию описаную в вопросе. У меня так не получилось. На локальной машине без проблем. Но здесь у тебя команды в баш не из пайпа прилетают, здесь у тебя из пайпа только аргументы прилетают

Comment: ключ `-a`, ответ ниже